# How to group array and mount select

Tags: php, arrays

I really need your help! How can I do to group the array results and assemble select.

### Database

[Image Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO3qf.png)

### PHP

```
<?php

 $rsPA = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM provas_agendadas WHERE status = 'A' ");

 foreach ($rsPA as $key => $rsRowPA){
   $dis1[] = explode("," , $rsRowPA['disciplinas']);
 }

 echo '<pre>';print_r($dis1);echo '</pre>';

?>
```

### Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => EJA-1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => EJA-1
            [1] => EJA-5
            [2] => TTI-1
        )

)
```

Expilando: From the result of the array, I will only get the number after the `-`, Ex: `EJA-1`, I only need `1`, which is the ID of the discipline table.

### End result you would like

[Image select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GCRk.png)

I thank everyone who can help me.

Comment: Firstly, you should not be storing a comma separated list of items in a field as this isn't normalized database design.  Secondly, you should also separate the values into the components so that you can use foreign keys to ensure validity of the data.

Comment: @NigelRen Can you help me in this situation?

Comment: In this case you could do something similar to what you are already doing - instead of just adding the results to a list in `$dis1[]` - `foreach()` over each one and `explode()` according to the `-`

Comment: @NigelRen How to join arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform an additional `for` loop, and `explode` each element on `-` and take the last part:

```
<?php

 $rsPA = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM provas_agendadas WHERE status = 'A' ");
 foreach ($rsPA as $key => $rsRowPA){
   $temp = explode("," , $rsRowPA['disciplinas']);
   foreach($temp as $elem){
    $number = explode('-',$elem);
    $number = end($number);
    $numbers[] = $number;
   }
 }
 $dis1 = array_count_values($numbers);

 echo '<pre>';print_r($dis1);echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: @Yejidoc you can check it out.